# Поменять максимальные и минимальные значения массива местами

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Test {
    static void Main() {
        int[] arrayTask = { 1, 2, -3, -6, -9, 10 };
        Console.WriteLine(
            " \a Максимальное значение массива: {0} \n  Минимальное значение: {1}",
            arrayTask.Max(),
            arrayTask.Min());  
    }
}
```

Я узнал максимальное и минимальное значения массива, как их поменять местами ? Надо определить индекс элемента по значению, это возможно ?

Comment: Индекс по значению определить нельзя, можно сохранить индекс для какого-то (максимального, минимального) значения и в дальнейшем оперировать им. Также обратите внимание, что в массиве может быть не один максимальный элемент, а два или более. Пример: {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2}

Comment: @AK, [почему нельзя?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy Блин, вы учите людей плохому ))) Потому что я предполагал, что топикстартер сам бежит по массиву и запоминает текущий самый максимальный элемент и его индекс. И в этой ситуации, когда мы прошли весь массив и нашли min и max повторно итерировать массив -- несколько негуманно и отбивает навык написания чистого кода. Лишняя итерация O(N) зачем нужна? Не нужна.

Comment: @AK как сохранить индекс для arrayTask.Max() ?

Comment: @Grundy проще чем я думал, вот как я должен был это найти ? По запросу "доступ к элементам массива c#" выдача googlе совершенно не приводит к таким результатам.

Comment: @Aleksey Budaev по запросу "поиск элемента в массиве".

Comment: @Grundy разве не проще применить Array.IndexOf (Array, Object) ?

Comment: @Aleksey Budaev, во-первых `Array.IndexOf<T>(T[], T)`, в противном случае каждый элемент массива будет упакован в Object, а затем распакован для сравнения. Во-вторых этот метод возвращает тебе первый элемент в массиве, удовлетворяющий условию. Их может быть несколько. Наконец, для этого тебе нужно знать искомый элемент. А это значит, что ты два раза пройдёшь поиском по массиву, о чём тебе и написал @AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю, что хорошее решение должно быть прежде всего легко читаемым. Поэтому давайте попробуем не экономить на количестве проходов в ущерб ясности кода.

Получаем вот такой простой вариант:

```
public static void SwapMaxAndMin(int[] array)
{
    if (array.Length == 0)
        return;

    var min = array.Min();
    var max = array.Max();

    if (min == max)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == min)
            array[i] = max;
        else if (array[i] == max)
            array[i] = min;
    }
}
```

Comment: С какой стороны посмотреть. Есть ещё гибкость и расширяемость. Вот понадобится тебе перейти от `int` к `T` протащить сюда `IComparer<T>`, и такой читабельный код моментально превратится в страхолюдину. Но в идеальном мире, где код не меняется со временем - сойдёт. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper: Гибкость и расширяемость — YAGNI. Потому что завтра не `int`, а `T`, послезавтра не максимум, а максимум по селектору, послепослезавтра не массив, а база данных. Предусмотреть заранее всё невозможно (а если пытаться, получится Java).

Comment: @VladD спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void SwapMaxAndMin(Int32[] array)
{
    int maxValue = int.MinValue;
    int minValue = int.MaxValue;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int minCount = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        int number = array[i];
        if (number > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = number;
            maxCount = 1;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
        else if (number == maxValue)
        {
            maxCount++;
        }

        if (number < minValue)
        {
            minValue = number;
            minCount = 1;
            minIndex = i;
        }
        else if (number == minValue)
        {
            minCount++;
        }
    }

    if (maxCount != 1)
        throw new NotSupportedException($"В массиве {maxCount} максимальных элементов.");
    if (minCount != 1)
        throw new NotSupportedException($"В массиве {minCount} минимальных элементов.");

    array[minIndex] = maxValue;
    array[maxIndex] = minValue;
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вы присваиваете <code> int maxValue = int.MinValue; int minValue = int.MaxValue </code> максимальные значения int ? А в первом витке цикла number принимает значение 0?

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev нет, неправильно

Comment: До первой итерации максимальное значение равно минимально возможному, минимальное - максимально возможному. Если в коллекции есть хотя бы один элемент, то на первой итерации они станут равны ему. В первом витке number будет равен первому элементу массива (i == 0). :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper  'int maxValue = int.MinValue;' Переменная maxValue принимает значение -2147483648. Почему нет?

Comment: @LunarWhisper Если number принимает значение 0, то все if - else не выполняются, а код сразу переходит к выполнению array[minIndex] = maxValue;
    array[maxIndex] = minValue;

Comment: За минимальное и максимальное значение лучше брать самый первый элемент коллекции и далее уже производить сравнения.

Comment: Объясните строку ' public static void SwapMaxAndMin(Int32[] array) ' это ведь не точка входа в программу.

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, верно, не точка входа, это процедура, которая переставляет минимальный и максимальный элементы, просто передайте в нее свой массив

Comment: @VladD, да не, не говорит вроде, но зато для пустого массива будет выброшено исключение

Comment: @VladD нет, не скажет, что легко проверить `SwapMaxAndMin(new int[] { int.MaxValue });`
@Vadim Prokopchuk это логичнее, но потребует добавить проверку на длину массива, чем лучше?

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev "почему нет" что? Условия выполняются, 0 не является магическим числом. Проще запустить и проверить, правда? ;)

Comment: @LunarWhisper: Ах, там начальное значение 0, понял.

Comment: А за что минус? Хорошее решение же.

Answer (score 0):

Для любителей абстракций и новых фишек языка:

```
public static void SwapMaxAndMin<T>(T[] source) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int IndexOfMax()
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
            if (source[index].CompareTo(source[i]) < 0) index = i;
        return index;
    }

    int IndexOfMin()
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
            if (source[index].CompareTo(source[i]) > 0) index = i;
        return index;
    }

    if (source.Length == 0) return;
    (int maxIndex, int minIndex) = (IndexOfMax(), IndexOfMin());
    (source[minIndex], source[maxIndex]) = (source[maxIndex], source[minIndex]);
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
static void Main()
{
    var array = new[] { 1, 2, -3, -6, -9, 10 };
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
    SwapMaxAndMin(array);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: 1. Ты игнорируешь то, что в массиве может быть несколько максимальных или минимальных элементов.
2. Зачем два раза проходить по массиву?

Comment: 1. Здесь уже автору виднее какой должен быть результат - игнорирование одинаковых элементов как у меня или исключение как у вас. 2. Разницы никакой - один раз пройти массив со стоимостью итерации 2 или два раза пройти массив со стоимостью итерации 1

Comment: Не говорите ерунды. Доступ к памяти (даже последовательный) - это не мгновенная операция. Один проход с двумя проверками: 0.2800165 сек., два прохода с одной проверкой: 0.4743305 сек. разница ровнёхонько в 2 раза, потому что сравнить две цифры из стека, которые в идеале ещё и процессор скэширует на порядок быстрее, чем два раза перебирать массив из управляемой кучи.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, откуда цифры такие?

Comment: Из теста вестимо. На рабочей машинке, массив в 100 000 000 элементов. Можешь повторить у себя и убедиться. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper, замедление дает использование `CompareTo`, если использовать вместо дженериков `int` и операторы `>` и `<`, то вариант с последовательными циклами всего на 20-30% медленнее, но, даже на миллионе объектов это незначительно. Ну и место для оптимизации в угоду читаемости всегда есть.

Comment: А давай перейдём от голословных высказываний к конкретным примерам. В моём нет никаких CompareTo. Есть только три цикла. В одном сравнение на больше и меньше, в другом только больше, в третьем только меньше. Первый отрабатывает в 2 раза быстрее, чем два оставшихся. И речь здесь не идёт о том заметна разница или нет. Она есть. Будет три цикла, будет в три раза медленнее. Обернёшь это в ещё один цикл и будет медленнее в 3*N раз. Да, время растёт линейно, а не по экспоненте. И не нужно пытаться везде писать максимально производительный код на goto. Но и просто так снижать перфоманс тоже плохо.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, ок.

Comment: `string.Concat(array.Select(e => e + " "))` зачем такое извращение? Неужели нельзя так: `String.Join(" ", array)` ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, вспоминал-вспоминал и не вспомнил

Answer (score 0):

Если несколько максимальных и минимальных, то меняем их ВСЕ!

```
int max = arrayTask.Max();
int min = arrayTask.Min();
arrayTask = arrayTask.Select(x=> x==min ? max : x==max ? min : x).ToArray();
```

пример не повторяющихся мин-макс:

> [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, -100, 0] => [1, 2, 2, 3, -100, 4, 0]

пример повторяющихся мин-макс:

> [1, 2, 4, 4, 4, -100, 0] => [1, 2, -100, -100, -100, 4, 0]

изменение по первому вхождению

```
int max = arrayTask.Max();
int min = arrayTask.Min();
int imax = arrayTask.Select((x,i) => x==max ? i : -1).First(x => x>=0);
int imin = arrayTask.Select((x,i) => x==min ? i : -1).First(x => x>=0);
arrayTask = arrayTask.Select((x,i) => i==imin ? max : i==imax ? min : x).ToArray();
```

> [1, -100, 4, 4, 4, -100, 0] => [1, 4, -100, 4, 4, -100, 0]

PS: Не знал какой вариант вам нужен при таких случаях, поэтому 2 варианта решения

PS2: Дабы избежать глюка при пустом массиве рекомендую:

```
if (arrayTask.length > 0) { /*Выбранный алгоритм*/ }
```

Comment: На пустом массиве выбросит ошибку. imax и imin всё-таки лучше (быстрее и читабельнее) получать при помощи IndexOf. Пять раз проходишь по массиву вместо одного. О.о

Comment: @Lunar Whisper, Прочитайте PS2, и не 5 раз, прочитайте про Linq... проход 3 раза

Comment: Max() - первый раз; Min() - второй раз; .Where(...).First(...) - ещё два раза, Select(...).ToArray() - пятый раз. Если тебе кажется, что Where и Select магическим образом схлопнутся в одну инструкцию, то нет, тебе кажется. Каждый из них создаст собственный IEnumerator, каждый из которых по одному разу пройдёт по массиву. Если ты хочешь объединить их в одно перечисление, это необходимо сделать явно. К слову, imax и imin тебе не нужны, раз уж вся логика находится внутри Select'а, ничто не мешает прямо там проверить на равенство min и max. Вот тогда будет 3 раза.

Comment: `.Where(...).First(...)` - отрабатывает до первого вхождения, и не 2 раза а максимум 1, но в большинстве случаев 2 итерации `.Where(...).First(...)` займут менее 1-го раза, еще раз рекомендую узнать как работают Linq запросы

Comment: @Lunar Whisper только что проверил, скорость моего алгоритма в 2 раза медленнее, но он работает при нескольких минимальных и максимальных элементах.

Comment: Мы же рассматриваем худший сценарий, когда максимальный и минимальный элементы расположены в самом конце. Недетерминированность временных затрат ещё никого до добра не доводила. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = array.Min();
var max = array.Max();

if (min == max)
    return "Минимум и максимум равны";

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == min)
        array[i] = max;
    else if (array[i] == max)
        array[i] = min;
}
```

Comment: Вы в одном случае возвращаете строку, а во втором что? Как это скомпилируется? И чем отличается от [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701475/218063)?

Comment: Во втором случае идет просто замена, а для вывода массива использовать снова цикл:          `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{Console.WriteLine(array[i]);}`